# creating dynamic fields and fill the data in it

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have below JSON data and `HTML` form, in which dynamically fields get created. This form work to send the data. But how to fill the fields by dynamically creating them

**json data**

```
$data = {"1":"a","3":"b","5":"c","2":"d","4":"e"}
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>

    <title>Add/Remove Input Fields Dynamically with jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
                var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
                $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
                    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
                });
                $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
                    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                        $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
        <label>Stuff</label>
        <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
            <div class="multi-fields">
                <div class="multi-field">
                    <select name="id[]">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" name="stuff[]">
                    <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you elaborate "But how to populate the given data in this dynamic fields." Do you mean: on select element the corresponding value should be put into the corresponding input?

Comment: what does your PHP look like that generates the form? specifically the `<select>` element.

Comment: @gaetanoM yes. so as the json contains the 5 elements. so 5 times the field will get created and data should get fill in it

Comment: @BizzyBob the php created to generated json data from this html. But now i am fetching those json data to fill back again

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop. In javascript you do something like:

```
var $data = {"1":"a","3":"b","5":"c","2":"d","4":"e"};
var formHTML = "";
$.each($data, function(key, value) { 
    var inputHTML = "<input name='"+key+"' value='"+value+"' type="text"/>\n";
    formHTML += inputHTML;
});
```

And then append formHTML inside your form.